# Using clean filter with fast-import

Tags: git, git-lfs, mkdocs

I'm using Git LFS and a tool that create commits using fast-import (Mike plugin for MKdocs), using the inline format. So the tool reads my files tracked and produce the Stream. As a consequence, Git LFS does not play well and files that should be taken car of, like "*.jpg", are not.

This is the code that is responsible for creating the fast-import Stream: https://github.com/jimporter/mike/blob/master/mike/git_utils.py#L301

Is there a way to use Git LFS with fast-import?